# Doxygen: How to use variable name instead of variable type in python?

Tags: python, doxygen, documentation-generation

I have a python code:

```
class Test:
    ## Step number in test steps list.
    current_step_number: int = 0
```

For this code Doxygen generates such piece of documentation:

```
Member Data Documentation
◆ int
   Test.Test.int       
   Step number in test steps list.
```

So Doxygen takes variable type int instead of variable name current_step_number.
How can I correct this behavior to have variable name in the documentation?

Comment: What version of doxygen are you using? It looks like this was probably [fixed in 1.8.15](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6462).

Comment: doxygen.exe -v says 1.8.15

Comment: Looks like the fix is for function arguments and here we are talking about class members. In the mentioned issue (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6462) there is the reference to tyhe fix https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/6544 and here is a reference to pep 3107. This pep is for functions. Is theer a pep for class variables etc. as well?

Answer (score 0):

Tried with version 1.9.1 and same result. My workaround:

```
class Test:
    ## Step number in test steps list.
    current_step_number: int
    current_step_number = 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).